# Error while trying to get data from an AJAX GET call with params passing Authotization header

Tags: php, ajax, html, file, http-headers

i need to make a call to a service  in GET method, passing 2 params and a specific Atuhorization header.

The problem is that if i pass params in GET, the service give me an OPTION error in the preflight mode.

Example with error header OPTION:

```
var token = 'fvvrgbrberb';
var settings = {
              "async": true,
              "crossDomain": true,
              "processData" : false,
              "url": "https://domain.ld/page/?param1=109&param2=598c37ab2b951",
              "method": "GET",
              "headers": {
                "authorization": "Bearer "+token,
              }
            }

            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
              console.info('Done: ',response);
            }).fail(function(response){
                console.info('error: ',response);
            });
```

Example with NO Error:

```
var token = 'fvvrgbrberb';
var settings = {
              "async": true,
              "crossDomain": true,
              "processData" : false,
              "url": "https://domain.ld/page/",
              "method": "GET",
              "headers": {
                "authorization": "Bearer "+token,
              }
            }

            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
              console.info('Done: ',response);
            }).fail(function(response){
                console.info('error: ',response);
            });
```

So if i don't send params in GET mode, all right, otherwise i got the error.

**MORE DETAIL**

in the ex 2 when i call service, obtain a json with the expect results { data: { some data } }, in the ex 1 i gave a json error (set by me) beacuse the service cannot found the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header in the request. I copied the code from POSTMAN, and with that, no problem in both case. Hope this help!

The goal is that i need to download a file if in the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION have a valid tocken.

**MORE INFO:**

If i use *php* *cUrl* instead of jQuery Ajax to make the call, no error found!

Hope this help!

Comment: What error? Be clear about what you want to do, what you have done, and what results you got.

Comment: @jdv in the ex 2 when i call service, obtain a json with the expect results { data: { some data } }, in the ex 1 i gave a json error (set by me) beacuse the service cannot found the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header in the request.
I copied the code from POSTMAN, and with that, no problem in both case. 
Hope this help!

Comment: Put details like this in the body of the question so everyone can see it in context.

Comment: did it! Thanks @jdv